# Enable log in class library project

Tags: logging, log4net

I create a class library project in `c#`, and I want to enable logging in that project using `log4net`. But `log4net` configuration is not working there, it is showing that I need a console project to enable the log in that.

Is there any way to configure log4net in my class library project without using any host application?

Comment: How is the class library even executing without a host application?

Answer (score 0):

2 ways of starting the logging for your dll:

```
// Configure log4net using the .config file
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch=true)]
// This will cause log4net to look for a configuration file
// called TestApp.exe.config in the application base
// directory (i.e. the directory containing TestApp.exe)
// The config file will be watched for changes.

// Configure log4net using the .log4net file
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFileExtension="log4net",Watch=true)]
// This will cause log4net to look for a configuration file
// called TestApp.exe.log4net in the application base
// directory (i.e. the directory containing TestApp.exe)
// The config file will be watched for changes.
```

Both will load the configuration file when the dll is loaded.